# Speeding up echo in ksh

Tags: performance, echo, ksh

I've got the below code working, in KSH but it takes the jobs a while to run generating `.tmp1`  it's slow in the `echo $LINE | cut -f 2,4 -d " " >> [file]` command, but I don't know why.

I'm guessing it's because it's due to the `echo` but I don't know; and I don't know how to re-write it to speed it up.

```
echo "Generating on zTempDay$count.tmp"
while read LINE
do
#Use Cut to trim down to right colums
#cut -b 11-26 $LINE
#mac=  cut -b 39-52 $LINE
#vlan= cut -b 62 $LINE
#This line pegs out the CPU - want to know why
echo $LINE | cut -f 2,4 -d " " >> zTempDay$count.tmp1
update_spinner
done < zTempDay$count.tmp
#Remove 'Incomplete' Enteries
#numOfIncomplete=grep "Incomplete" zTempDay$count.tmp1 | wc -l
sed -e "/Incomplete/d" zTempDay$count.tmp1 > zTempDay$count.tmp2
#Use sort to sort by MAC
#Use uniq to remove duplicates
sort +1 -2 zTempDay$count.tmp2 | uniq -f 1 > zTempDay$count.tmp3

#Format Nicely
tr ' ' '\t' < zTempDay$count.tmp3 > zTempDay$count.tmp4
##Want to put a poper progress bar in   if program remains slow
#dialog --gauge "Formatting Data: Please wait" 10 70 0
#bc 100*$count/$maxDaysInMonth
```

Example Data

```
Internet  10.174.199.193          -   8843.e1a3.1b40  ARPA   Vlan####
Internet  10.1.103.206          110   f4ce.46bd.e2e8  ARPA   Vlan####
```

Intended Product (using a tab between IP and MAC)

```
10.174.199.193      8843.e1a3.1b40
10.1.103.206        f4ce.46bd.e2e8
```

Comment: `awk '{print $2 "\t" $4}' infile | sort +1 -2 > outfile` ? Add any other stuff that you need after the `|sort...` using more '|'s . Progress bar will just slow you down. Have faith! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  That certainly does make it a good deal faster.  I still have a few lines to purge (not shown in example data sadly) but I think I can use SED to find and remove them.

I agree the progress bar would slow me down; if the program gets sped up enough then the point is moot. :)

But why was it slow to start with?  Is echo just a really slow command?

Comment: as you work in Unix scripting, you have to learn to count the number of processes you are creating. With my script, there is 1 process, with your script there is a master process (the while loop) AND at least 1 process per line of data that you're reading. While you can use sed to clean up your data, you can almost certainly get the same results using awk code like `awk '/Dont_process/ next ; /DontProcess2/ next ; { print $2 "\t" $4}' infile > outfile`. Of course you have to  modify the exclusion targets 'DontProcess2' as needed. You can also use reg-expressions to exclude. Post some samp data

Comment: Oh wow, that explains why the CPU gets pegged.  The files I'm working with are 200,000-900,000 lines in size, per file.

Internet  129.82.171.88           0   Incomplete      ARPA
 was the bad data but using the '/Incomplete/' {next} ; inside awk seems to have solved it...  the rest of the bad data reuslted of me mangling the data badly after that.  :)

Comment: awk is your friend. see tutorial at www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html AND all things awk at http://awk.info . Good luck!

Comment: Thank you a ton. :)  I will spend some time looking into awk - it does see more powerful than i first gave it credit for. :)

Comment: be sure to accept  your own answer to gain valuable reputation points ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*awk '/Incomplete/ {next} ; 
{print $2 "\t" $4}' zTempDay01.tmp | sort +1 -2  | uniq -f 1 > outfile*
```

works like a charm thanks to Shellter's help.  Thank you! :)